# How to fix HDMI in Debian (output not working)?

Tags: debian, hdmi

Randomly my computer's HDMI output (running **Debian 8**) doesn't output anything to HDMI (my screen says "no signal"). Other times it does.
The only thing I can say is that if it works just after boot, it works always. Otherwise it doesn't work at all and I have to restart my machine.

I made some research and apparently nothing is wrong:

- I have an NVidia graphical card supporting Optimus technology. So I'm using **bumblebee** with proprietary nvidia software **uninstalled**
- lsmod | grep 'hdmi' returns several items:

> ```
> snd_hda_codec_hdmi     45118  1 
> snd_hda_codec         104463  5 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_controller
> snd_pcm                88662  4 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_controller
> snd                    65244  18 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_pcm,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel
> ```

How can I diagnostic what's wrong with my HDMI output?

Comment: Running Debian 11 (testing) at the time, I had the "no signal" problem until I ran the following command: `dbus-launch dolphin` The following tip gave me the trick: https://forum.manjaro.org/t/unable-to-create-io-slave-klauncher-said-error-loading-usr-lib-qt-plugins-kf5-kio-file-so/25866

Comment: @Olivier The page you've rederred to doesn't exist anymore. Could you elaborate, please? I've just updated to Debian 11 and my HDMI output doesn't work.